# Discrete Mathematics - Ice Cream random samples

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

How would you solve the following problem with Discrete Mathematics, and what is the answer?

Suppose there are 5 different types of ice cream you like. How many random samples ice cream must be eaten to guarantee that you have had at least 7 samples of one type?

Comment: Please share with us your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: I don't have any, discrete is impossible

Comment: Hint : You can think of this as a generalization of the pigeon hole principle.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: You can eat $30$ samples without getting $7$ of the same type; how? What happens if you eat more than that?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If you have eaten $(5)(6)$ samples, you **might** not have eaten $7$ of any flavour, since you might have eaten $6$ of each flavour.  But anything over that $\dots$. In your answer, you might be expected to mention and use the Pigeonhole Principle.