# 101 positive integers placed on a circle

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

A Pigeonhole Principle problem:

> 101 positive integers are placed on a circle whose sum is 300. Prove
>   that it is possible to choose from these numbers some consecutive
>   numbers whose sum is equal to 200.

*(I don't know if the word 'consecutive' is appropriate in this case ,I mean that these numbers follow each other on that circle)*

Comment: Do you mean two consecutive numbers?

Comment: @DanielLittlewood Surely not: use one hundred $1$s and a single $200$; then you cannot find two consecutive numbers whose sum is $200$.

Comment: Adjacent is a better term, I think. The problem should be the same as the sum of adjacent numbers is 100.

Comment: Yes, adjacent is a better word .I mean adjacent not consecutive.

Comment: I think the circle here can be viewed as a string and the problem asks to prove that there is a substring whose sum is 200.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Start at a certain position and form sums of subsequences of length $1, 2, \dotsc, 101$ starting at that position and going in clockwise direction.  This is an increasing sequence of $101$ numbers so there are two different entries that are equal $\bmod$ $100$ (end in the same two digits).  The difference between those entries is a positive multiple of $100$ and less than $300$ so either $100$ or $200$.  This difference corresponds to a subsequence of numbers on the circle with sum either $100$ or $200$.  If it is $200$ we're done, otherwise take the complement of that sequence.

Comment: When you say "subsequence" in line 5, you mean consecutive right?

Comment: @alancalvitti Of course.

Comment: That's what I thought. What's the general principle that enabled you to solve this problem? Would I find it in, eg, Bona's *Walk Through Combinatorics*?

Comment: @alancalvitti I've known the pigeon hole principle for more than twentyfive years, plenty of time to practice!

Comment: I'm familiar with the principle, but curious how you applied it here.

Comment: @alancalvitti $101$ pigeons in $100$ holes...  ($101$ numbers and only $100$ possibilities for their last two digits.)