# Arc sums for a circle of $k$ positive integers whose total sum is $n$

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, pigeonhole-principle

[This problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282589/a-pigeonhole-principle-problem/282641) got me thinking about the following more general scenario:

Suppose you have $k$ positive integers with total sum $n$, and you arrange them in a circle.

Given such an arrangement, you could look at different sums of consecutively placed positive integers along "arcs" of this circle. Furthermore, you could ask which numbers must *always* appear in an arc for a given $k$ and $n$, i.e., regardless of which $k$ positive integers summing to $n$ are chosen and how they are arranged around the circle.

Let $A_{k, n}$ be the set of numbers that necessarily appear in some arc for every circular arrangement of $k$ positive integers whose sum is $n$. (Of course, this set is nonempty iff $k \leq n$.)

Trivially, $n \in A_{k, n}$. (Proof: take the arc that corresponds to the entire circle.)

The linked problem above demonstrates that $200 \in A_{101, 300}$ using the pigeonhole principle.

Another obvious fact: given a positive integer $m < n$ with $m \in A_{k, n}$, then $n-m \in A_{k,n}$ as well.

For the linked problem above, this means that $300 - 200 = 100 \in A_{101, 300}$ too.

Of course, this latter fact is proven by taking complement arcs.

**Questions:**

$1.$ Has this general scenario already been studied under some other name?

$2.$ Is there an easy way to determine the elements of $A_{k,n}$ in general?

$3.$ If the answers to $1$ and $2$ are both no, what can you show for some special cases?

As a final, very simple example: $A_{n,n} = \{1, \ldots, n\}$.

(Ideally, if you are going to answer $3$, it would be with a less trivial proposition!)

Comment: You can use the same idea as in that earlier problem to get some elements of $A_{k,n}$. All $i$ and $n-i$, with $i<k$ and either $n=3i$ or $n<2i$ will be in $A_{k,n}$.

Comment: No, this is not exhaustive. For example, if $n<2k$, then $1,n-1 \in A_{k,n}$. I am not sure if adding these covers the entire $A_{k,n}$ either. We can get some conditions on $A_{k,n}$ by placing some particular $k$ integers in the circle. For example, let the $k$ integers be $1,1,\ldots,1,n-k+1$. From this we get that $A_{k,n} \subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,k-1\} \cup \{n-k+1,n-k+2,\ldots,n\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equivalent problem: $k$ distinct elements are selected from the integers $\mod n$; which $\mod n$ differences between pairs are forced?  The equivalence is to assign, to a set of $k$ positive integers written around a circle, its set of clockwise arc sums $\mod n$, including $0$ for the empty sum.

Pairs at a difference of $d$ can be represented as an undirected graph by joining any such pair by an edge. The structure of the graph depends only on $g = \gcd(d,n)$, it is a union of $g$ disjoint cycles all of length $\frac{n}{g}$.  A cycle of length $L$ can accomodate up to $\lfloor \frac{L}{2} \rfloor$ vertices not connected by an edge.

Thus $d$, and any distance with the same value of $g$, is forced if and only if $k > g \lfloor \frac{n}{2g} \rfloor$.  The condition for $k$ to force $g$ is then  $k > n/2$ when $2g|n$, and $k > \frac{n-g}{2}$ when $n$ and $g$ are divisible by the same power of $2$.  This is the necessary and sufficient condition for values of $d$ with $(d,n)=g$ to be in the set of forced arc sums $A_{k,n}$.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a special case: If $k \leq n < 2k$ then $A_{k,n} = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.

---

The OP has already shown that $A_{n,n} = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$, so let's assume $k < n < 2k$.

Start at the largest positive integer on the circle.  Since $n > k$, this must be at least $2$.  Let $s_j$, $1 \leq j \leq kn$, be the sum of the $j$ consecutive values moving clockwise from this starting point.  Note that $s_{kn}$ adds up numbers that wrap around the circle $n$ times.

Let $S = \{s_j \, |\,  1 \leq j \leq kn\}$.  The values in $S$ are all distinct.  Moreover, the smallest is at least $2$ and the largest is exactly $n^2$.

For any positive integer $i$, let $T = \{s_j + i \, | \,  1 \leq j \leq kn\}$.  The values in $T$ are all distinct.  Moreover, the smallest is at least $2+i$ and the largest is exactly $n^2+i$.

Together, $S$ and $T$ contain $2kn$ elements, all of which must be among $n^2+i-1$ values.  The pigeonhole principle says that if $2kn > n^2 + i - 1$, then at least one element from $S$ and one element from $T$ must have the same value.  Rearranging, this inequality is equivalent to $i < (2k-n)n + 1$.  Since $2k - n \geq 1$, the inequality is true for any $i \leq n$.

So, if $1 \leq i \leq n$, there exist indices $j$ (from $S$) and $m$ (from $T$) such that $s_j = s_m + i$.  But $s_j - s_m = i$ means that the sequence of integers starting at position $m+1$ and ending at position $j$ sums to $i$.  Moreover, since once around the circle yields a sum of $n$, and $i \leq n$, this sequence does not go all the way around the circle.  Thus if $1 \leq i \leq n$, there exists an arc sum equal to $i$.

Therefore, $A_{k,n} = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ for $k \leq n < 2k$.

Comment: $+1$ Nice idea!

Comment: Some simple observations for the next-highest case: $A_{k,2k}$ contains only even integers (take the circle of all $2$s) and if $k$ is even, it contains only multiples of $4$ (take alternating $1$s and $3$s).  Also, $A_{k,n}$ is always disjoint from the interval $[k,n-k]$ (take all $1$s except for one large).  What other designs can produce negative results?

Answer (score 4):

Follow-up, slightly too long for a comment: did some small experiments, and it appears (empirically) that $A_{k,2k}$ consists of exactly those integers having at least the $2$-adic valuation of $2k$ (e.g. $A_{6,12} = \{4,8,12\}$).  The pattern holds up to $k\le 17$, after which my program takes more than a few minutes to run.

It seems things do get interesting when $n - 2k$ is small and non-negative.  It appears that $A_{k,n} = \{n\}$ most of the time, especially when $n$ is much larger than $k$ (a precise form of this statement probably isn't hard to prove, perhaps for $n \ge 3k$).

Here's another interesting pattern:

- $A_{4,n} = \{n\}$ for all $8 \le n \le 30$, except $A_{4,9} = \{3,6,9\}$.
- $A_{5,n} = \{n\}$ for all $11 \le n \le 30$, except $A_{5,12} = \{4,8,12\}$.
- $A_{6,n} = \{n\}$ for all $13 \le n \le 30$, except $A_{6,15} = \{5,10,15\}$.
- $A_{7,n} = \{n\}$ for all $16 \le n \le 30$, except $A_{7,18} = \{6,12,18\}$.

One might naturally be tempted to conjecture that either $A_{k,n} = \{1,\ldots,n\}$ or $A_{k,n} = \{n\}$, unless $n = 2k$ or $n = 3(k-1)$.  But the truth is not quite so convenient, for we also have

- $A_{7,15} = \{3,5,6,9,10,12,15\}$.

This seems to be the first example that does not consist of an arithmetic progression mod $n$ (however, note that it is precisely the set of non-units mod $15$).

Comment: It turns out for all $k \le 17$ that $A_{k,2k+1}$ is precisely equal to the set of non-units mod $2k+1$.  Admittedly there isn't much variety in factorization for such small numbers (I doubt I can reach $2k+1 = 3\cdot 5\cdot 7$), but I'm surprised by the level of number-theoretic content here.

Comment: It is true that $A_{k,2k+1}$ is always the nonunits.

Comment: It is also the case that $k \leq (n/3)$ is never enough to force any value less than $n$ into $A_{k,n}$, and $k > (n/2)$ forces all.