# There are $101$ positive integers that sum to $300$. Can we find a subset of these integers that sums to $100$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

We are given a set of $101$ positive integers that sum to $300$.

Since summation of $101$ distinct numbers cannot be $300$, repetition among the $101$ positive integers exists.

Can we choose a group of numbers from the $101$ positive integers such that the sum of the elements in the group is $100$?

If not, please tell me a counter-example.

Comment: Choose the numbers $1001, 1002,\ldots, 1101$.

Comment: I edited the question. Please check that I did not change the intended meaning.

Comment: Let $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{101}\}$ be the elements and consider the $101$ subsets $\{x_1\},\{x_1,x_2\}$, $\ldots$, $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{101}\}$. Now consider the sum of the elements of these subsets $\mod 100$. For more info see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282589/101-positive-integers-placed-on-a-circle).