# Pigeonhole principle exercises

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, pigeonhole-principle

I have an exam in combinatorics on Friday and the pigeonhole principle is a part of the material. Can someone give me a reference to a book with the hardest(!) questions on this material? Thank you very much, it can help me a lot!

Comment: [Here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Pigeonhole_Principle) are a few problems.

Comment: You probably don't want the hardest such questions.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/194312/18398

Answer (score 1):

The book "Problem Solving Through Problems" by Loren C. Larson has a section on the pigeonhole principle that I like very much. A favourite application of mine is showing that every 2-colouring of the complete graph on 6 vertices contains a triangle whose edges are all the same colour.

Answer (score 0):

In the book 'Proofs From THE BOOK' by Aigner & Ziegler there is a chapter on combinatorics which contains some nice problems.
Here's a neat problem from 'Combinatorics and Graph Theory' by Harris et al: Let $a_1, a_2, a_3 \dots a_n$ be a sequence of integers. Prove the existence of integers $1\le j\le k\le n$ such that $\sum_{i=j}^k a_i $ is a multiple of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

One of Paul Erdos's favorites:

We choose $n+1$ numbers from the set $\{1, 2, \cdots, 2n\}$. Prove that there are some two of our $n+1$ numbers such that one divides the other.