# Arrangement of $100$ points inside $13\times18$ rectangle

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

> Prove that you can't arrange 100 points inside a $13\times18$
>   rectangle so that the distance between any two points is at least 2.

I tried many ways to divide the rectangle, but I can't get the parts to be small enough, and also less than 100.

Answer (score 8):

Draw a circle of radius 1 around each point and imagine a "frame" around the rectangle of width 1.  How much of the expanded rectangle will the (non-overlapping) circles fill?